# Reactjs List that reveals itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, arraylist

I'm working on a project. Its my FYP.
I was wondering is there any library that can help me build a list in Reactjs that reveals itself like in Facebook, fb posts reveal as we scroll down.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a library for that ? keep the list in a state variable and just add the item at the end of the list , so whenever a new item is added it would trigger a re-render of the `return` in the component and in the `return` you could just iterate through the array

Comment: Its because my application ill use lists in many component and I've applied many filter functions already on those list.
Thats why I'm thinking of using some library to manage them further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course!

Some of libraries you can use:

- [react-infinite-scroller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller)
- [react-infinite-scroll-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)
- [react-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller)
- [react-infinite-scroll-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-hook)

However, there is no essence to use a library for this. You can do it by yourself. The only thing you need to do is to add an event listener for scroll event. And after a specific amount of scroll, show new data. That's it.

Comment: @MoeezShahid please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.